# Synching Django Session with Database

Tags: python, django, database, session, backend

I'm working on an E-Commerce website with Django.
I'm currently trying to build the shopping cart but there's a challenge.
The shopping cart was built with the Django session. However, I need to retain this cart for each user even after logout, because it wipes the session upon logout.
I understand I have to make use of a database in some way.

```
views.py

from django.contrib.auth import user_logged_out, user_logged_in
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from django.views.decorators.http import require_POST
from chollo_cart.chollo_cart import Cart
from chollo_cart.forms import CartAddProductForm
from chollo_main.models import Product


# Create your views here.

@require_POST
def add_to_cart(request, product_id):
    cart = Cart(request)
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
    form = CartAddProductForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        clean_data = form.cleaned_data
        cart.add(product=product,
                 quantity=clean_data['quantity'],
                 overide_quantity=clean_data['override'])
        return redirect('chollo_cart:cart_detail')


# Note the addition of 'id=' that was not formerly there
@require_POST
def remove_from_cart(request, product_id):
    cart = Cart(request)
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
    cart.remove(product)
    return redirect('chollo_cart:cart_detail')


def cart_detail(request):
    cart = Cart(request)
    for item in cart:
        item['update_quantity_form'] = CartAddProductForm(initial={
            'quantity': item['quantity'],
            'override': True
        })
    return render(request, 'chollo_main/cart-details.html', {'cart': cart})
```

Here's the `cart.py`

```
from decimal import Decimal
from django.conf import settings
from chollo_main.models import Product


class Cart:
    def __init__(self, request):
        """
        initialize the cart
        """
        self.session = request.session
        chollo_cart = self.session.get(settings.CART_SESSION_ID)
        if not chollo_cart:
            # save an empty chollo_cart in the session
            chollo_cart = self.session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID] = {}
        self.chollo_cart = chollo_cart

    def add(self, product, quantity=1, override=1, overide_quantity=False):
        """
        Add a product to the cart or update its quantity
        :param product:
        :param quantity:
        :param override:
        :param overide_quantity:
        :return:
        """
        product_id = str(product.id)
        if product_id not in self.chollo_cart:
            self.chollo_cart[product_id] = {'quantity': 0,
                                            'price': str(product.price)}
        if overide_quantity:
            self.chollo_cart[product_id]['quantity'] = quantity
        else:
            self.chollo_cart[product_id]['quantity'] += quantity

        self.save()

    def save(self):
        # mark the session as "modified" to make sure it gets saved
        self.session.modified = True

    def remove(self, product):
        """
        Remove a product from the cart.
        :param product:
        :return:
        """
        product_id = str(product.id)
        if product_id in self.chollo_cart:
            del self.chollo_cart[product_id]
            self.save()

    def __iter__(self):
        """
        Iterate over the items in the cart and get the products
        from the database.
        :return:
        """
        product_ids = self.chollo_cart.keys()
        # get the product objects and add them to the cart
        products = Product.objects.filter(id__in=product_ids)
        chollo_cart = self.chollo_cart.copy()
        for product in products:
            chollo_cart[str(product.id)]['product'] = product
        for item in chollo_cart.values():
            item['price'] = Decimal(item['price'])
            item['total_price'] = item['price'] * item['quantity']
            yield item

    def __len__(self):
        """
        Count all items in the cart.
        :return:
        """
        return sum(item['quantity'] for item in self.chollo_cart.values())

    def get_total_price(self):
        """
        Count all items in the cart.
        :return:
        """

        return sum(Decimal(item['price']) * Decimal(item['quantity']) for item in self.chollo_cart.values())

    def clear(self):
        # Remove cart from session
        del self.session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID]
        self.save()
```